# how to perform sequelize bulk insert in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm writing rest using nodejs,sequelize and MySQL.
I want to insert 6000 record in MySQL table using a bulk insert of sequelize so bulk insert is possible or not?

```
// temp is my array 
SymbolsData.bulkCreate(temp)
        .then((dbRes) => {
            console.log(dbRes);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('error', err);
        });
```

Comment: use array to insert all data

Comment: Can you please explain what error that you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my temp array, there are many objects without object key so I added object key based on the database field name and then pass that array to bulkInsert and it's working good. I missed the object key.